# How to increase figure width in a Matlab live script?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I'm using a Matlab Live script in which I'd like to use some subfigures. As the Standard figure size only uses a small section of the screen widths, I tried to enlarge the figure as follows:

```
h = figure;
subplot(1,2,1);
subplot(1,2,2);
set(h, 'Position', [0 0 1000 500])
```

This works entirely fine, for 'normal' figure Windows, but appearently not for in-line figures in live scripts.

As to be seen from the screenshots below, in the live script, the figure's size only increases to a small amount (fig. 1 -> fig. 2) and even decreases after a certain width (fig. 3).

Any ideas on how I can further increase the used pagewidth in the live script, or hints on what I'm doing wrong are appreciated.

Thanks

fig. 1

[image: 1]

fig. 2

[image: 2]

fig. 3

[image: 3]

Comment: What version of Matlab do you use? This works quite well to me: `set(h, 'Position', [0 0 1000 500])`

Comment: I used 2017b when setting up the example above. However I've retried it now on a different system with 2018a. As you described it does work exactly as intended there. So I suppose that it's a solved bug then.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach that seems to work for me (R2020b) is to use normalized units when declaring the position:

```
h = figure();
subplot(1,2,1); 
subplot(1,2,2); 
set(h,'Units','normalized','Position',[0 0 1 .5]);
```

The first two elements of the Position array tell MATLAB where to place the bottom-right corner (position (0,0)) whereas the last two elements determine the figure's X and Y size. The above snippet results in figures as large as the text, as seen here:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wp8G.png).

Answer (score -1):

You may try to use use axis property. Please refer in here:
https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axis.html

Comment: I can't really find any axis properties that would help me with this concern of extending the whole figure's size and not only adjusting limits or adjust to data width etc.